# Spring Configuration: 2 beans with same class reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

Spring-configuration: I have created 2 beans with reference to same class but different database sessions.

```
<bean id="abc1" class="abc">
<bean id="abc2" class="abc">
```

Now is there any way to set bean with id "abc1" as default bean for autowiring and use abc2 for autowiring when mentioned explicitly like this:

```
@Autowiring
@Qualifier("abc2")
private abc obj;
```

**Solution:**

```
<bean id="abc1" class="abc" primary="true">
```

makes abc1 default one to be autowired.

for creating an instance of abc2, we can use this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc2")
private abc obj;
```

Comment: Can u accept upvote it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@primary` annotation or `primary` attribute of xml is used exactly for that purpose. Here is the details of the same. It is pretty well documented here.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

So if you mention `<bean id="abc1" class="abc" primary="true"/>` it will get priority over `abc2`, and you can use `@Qualifier` for `abc2` wherever you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation, then Spring will lookup for a bean with the same name as the `private` member. For example:

```
@Autowired
private abc abc1; //Spring will search for a bean with id="abc1"
```

This was you can use `abc1` as a *default* value.

If you don't want to make Spring search for a specific bean, then you can trigger the `@Qualifier` and then Spring will not care how the member is called, but will assign it's value to refer to the bean that has the same `id` pointed out in the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc2")
private abc theNameDoesNotMatter;
```

Comment: I guess he was looking for @primary annotation or equivalent of it. I hope my answer provides what he wants.